# flask socketio send different messages to different clients at the same time

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

I have a flask-socketio server and several react socket.io-client namespaces connected to it.
Clients are in the same ip and port but in different namespaces like /finalResponse, /algoSignal etc.

Client app

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Connecting to backend api for data
    const { dispatch } = this.props;

    socket = io(`http://${IP.clientOrderFeedFlaskIP}:6050/algoSignal`);
    dispatch(loadClientOrdersDataSocket(socket));
    
    var interval = setInterval(()=>{
       socket.emit('getdata')
       console.log(socket.connected)
     },2000)
     this.setState({interval:interval})

    socket.emit('update')

    socket.on("algo_signal_data", (res) => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(res))
      dispatch(ClientOrdersData(res));
    });
  }
```

Here it sends up an interval to ping the server with 'getdata' to request every 2 seconds. There is an event bucket to handle incoming data in 'algo_signal_data'.
'update' bucket is to get data on refresh.
Similar to this I have around 8-9 clients in different namespaces.

Backend server

```
@socket.on('getdata', namespace = '/algoSignal')
def algoSignal():
    # global algosig
    lastOrderUpdated = json.loads(pingConn.get('lastOrderUpdated'))
    if lastOrderUpdated != '0':
        print('---------------------sent algo signal data ---------------------')
        algosig = SymphonyOrderRaw(mongoIp).algoSignal.to_json(orient = 'records')
        emit('algo_signal_data', algosig, broadcast = True)
        pingConn.set('lastOrderUpdated', json.dumps('0'))
    else:
        emit(json.dumps(200))

@socket.on('getdata', namespace='/finalResponse')
def getfinalResponse():
    # global finalres
    lastOrderUpdated = json.loads(pingConn.get('lastOrderUpdated'))
    if lastOrderUpdated != '0':
        finalres = FinalResponse(mongoIp).finalResponse.to_json(orient = 'records')
        print('--------------------sent final Response data----------------')
        # print(finalres)
        emit('response_data', finalres, broadcast = True)
        pingConn.set('lastOrderUpdated', json.dumps('0'))
        
    else:
        emit(json.dumps(200))
```

I have event buckets like these who recieve the 'getdata' prompt and check if the database was updated. If yes, it sends the data else it sends status code.

The expected result is that each client page should recieve data when db is updated.
The problem is that when I open multiple client pages in seperate tabs, The server only sends the data to one page. But when the other pages is refreshed, then data is updated in those also.

Update bucket

```
@socket.on('update', namespace = '/algoSignal')
def update2():
    algosig = SymphonyOrderRaw(mongoIp).algoSignal.to_json(orient = 'records')
    emit('algo_signal_data', algosig, broadcast = True)
```

This is the output at the server terminal

```
(flask-venv) mockAdmin@python-react:~/RMS-git/FlaskServerCodes/serverFlask$ python3 main.py
Starting
 * Restarting with stat
Starting
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 113-048-226
(59454) wsgi starting up on http://10.160.0.2:6050
(59454) accepted ('103.62.42.27', 65522)
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vTi HTTP/1.1" 200 401 0.000859
algo signal client connected
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vVA&sid=65d328eeffb943a5a2ad80ee4216c856 HTTP/1.1" 200 219 0.000986
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vVh&sid=65d328eeffb943a5a2ad80ee4216c856 HTTP/1.1" 200 249 0.000353
(59454) accepted ('103.62.42.27', 65523)
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vWP&sid=65d328eeffb943a5a2ad80ee4216c856 HTTP/1.1" 200 219 0.001710
(59454) accepted ('103.62.42.27', 65524)
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vWQ&sid=65d328eeffb943a5a2ad80ee4216c856 HTTP/1.1" 200 235 0.000171
(59454) accepted ('103.62.42.27', 65525)
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vWZ HTTP/1.1" 200 401 0.000345
(59454) accepted ('103.62.42.27', 65526)
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vX6&sid=65d328eeffb943a5a2ad80ee4216c856 HTTP/1.1" 200 235 0.000255
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vX5&sid=65d328eeffb943a5a2ad80ee4216c856 HTTP/1.1" 200 219 0.005536
final response client connected
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vXg&sid=8e278beb8e5a4f77b5b203e28af9b596 HTTP/1.1" 200 219 0.000881
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vXl&sid=65d328eeffb943a5a2ad80ee4216c856 HTTP/1.1" 200 235 0.000180
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vY4&sid=8e278beb8e5a4f77b5b203e28af9b596 HTTP/1.1" 200 252 0.000208
(59454) accepted ('103.62.42.27', 65527)
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vYk&sid=8e278beb8e5a4f77b5b203e28af9b596 HTTP/1.1" 200 260 0.000265
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vYj&sid=8e278beb8e5a4f77b5b203e28af9b596 HTTP/1.1" 200 219 0.002399
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vZL&sid=8e278beb8e5a4f77b5b203e28af9b596 HTTP/1.1" 200 235 0.000189
103.62.42.27 - - [31/Dec/2021 11:22:05] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NuF2vZM&sid=8e278beb8e5a4f77b5b203e28af9b596 HTTP/1.1" 200 219 0.005291
-----------------------------sent final Response data-----------------------
```

How can I send data to all the open client pages at the same time from a single server?

Comment: You haven't enabled Socket.IO logs on the server. See the troubleshooting section of the documentation to learn how to do it, then update your question with those logs. Side note, you are not using WebSocket. Any reason for that?

Comment: @Miguel. I am not familiar with the inner workings of the socketio modules. What do you mean by using WebSocket.

Comment: The main reason to use Socket.IO is that it allows the server to push data to clients without the client having to poll for this data. This is done over the WebSocket protocol. If you don't have WebSocket, the Socket.IO client is polling for updates. These are the constant GET and POST HTTP requests that you see in your log above.

Comment: @Miguel. Oh I got it now. The reason for not using WebSocket is that I am using the developement web server which does not allow web socket transport. When I use a production server this problem will most likely go away.

Comment: If you use Flask 2.x you can add simple-websocket to your virtualenv and that will give you WebSocket support.